# Bootstrap Modal: Android browser

Tags: android, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a website and I have an issue with the bootstrap modal, specifically on android's stock browser "Internet".

The modal works in every browser, including IE and Safari, I have no idea why its not working on android.

I even added a custom jQuery function in order to achieve this. But it didn't work

**Here's the code with the custom javascript:**

Markup

```
<button id="upload-btn-green" type="button" class="btn" >
    Upload
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group main-btns">
                    <a id="import"
                       name="import"
                       class="btn btn-import"
                       href="/redirect">
                       <img id="facebook-image" src="/images/fb.png" alt="facebook icon">
                    </a>
                <div id="divisor"></div>
                    <label id="folder" class="btn btn-upload select-image-btn">
                        <input id="upload" type="file" style="display: none;" >
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$( "#upload-btn-green" ).click(function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Answer (score 1):

I recently completed a site using bootstrap 4 .modal. Looking at your modal code, I can't help but think you're missing something. Honestly it is really hard to say because you didn't include the other part of the modal or details of exactly what you're trying to accomplish. I did find a bug in your code above.

**change this**

```
aria labelledby="myModalLabel"
```

**to this**

```
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
```